# Programmatically render (export as Image) Class Diagrams (Visual Studio)

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-extensions, class-diagram

In my projects I actively use `class diagrams` (*.cd). I'd like to export my diagrams programmatically (e.g. during the build, or on my CI server) in order to use them on Wiki pages, etc.

I know that I can do it manually via "Export Diagram As Image" dialog
[image: Export Diagram As Image]

But the diagrams change rather often so I'm curious **is there a way to do it programmatically (using any library, utility, etc)?**

Answer (score 1):

> But the diagrams change rather often so I'm curious is there a way to do it programmatically (using any library, utility, etc)?

you can use method named GetObject to get the Diagram of the underlying implementation. This type has a method CreateBitmap. The following link provide a complete code sample for your reference.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff469815.aspx

Update:
The UML diagrams support are:

1.Class Diagram

2.UseCase Diagram

3.Sequence Diagram

4.Component Diagram

5.Activity Diagram

6.Layer Diagram

Comment: Just to be absolutely sure: does this approach work for Class Diagrams too? (not UML diagrams from Modeling Architecture projects).

Comment: Yes, please check the following extension. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=LazzarottoFabrizio.CreateBitmapDiagram

Comment: OK, thanks for answer. I'll try this solution on the weekend. I'm still not sure about it, because UML Class diagram (.classdiagram from Modeling Project) is completely different from Class Diagram (.cd from another project types, e.g. C# class library), they have different format and look different.

Comment: If you have any issues, please free feel let me know.